# Android AppWidgetProvider and screen updating?

Tags: android, timer, widget

I am making a clock widget for the android home screen using AppWidgetProvider.

I have it calling the TImerTask class that updates all my values using this code:

```
@Override
 public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
 {
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), 1, 1000);
 }
```

In the TimerTasks `run()` I am setting a bunch of text views to the relevent values.

My problem is that this seems to work fine, but it makes my home screen unresponsive, probably due to updating it every second.

How do I fix this and still have it update the display at the correct time? (I only need to see minutes not seconds, but I want the minutes to change at the correct second.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to ACTION_TIME_TICK broadcast. It is posted every minute exactly when time is changed. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK.

Code samples:
http://kfb-android.blogspot.com/2009/04/registering-for-timetick-after-reboot.html
http://www.hostingjava.it/-frusso/android/tips/tips_0002.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Use `AlarmManager`. Set the time for the repeating alarm. Update your app widget when the alarm goes off.